# How to stop Windows mouse handler in Python?

Tags: python, winapi, tkinter

I made a mouse automation program and I have the following function which I call with a Tkinter "after" method ( root.after(1000,start_mouse) )

```
def start_mouse():
    """Staring the mouse click recording"""
    global root, FLAG, CLICKS, T, q, timeList, clickThreadId
    q = Queue.Queue()
    threading.Thread(target=stack).start()
    clickThreadId = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()

    def onclick(event):
        """Mouse handler"""
        global timeList, T, FLAG, q
        timeList.append(int(round(time.time() * 1000)) )
        Tt = timeList[-1] - timeList[-2]

        print event.Position[0],event.Position[1], Tt
        if FLAG == 2:
            temp_l =str(event.Position[0])+","+str(event.Position[1])+","+str(Tt)+"\n"
            q.put_nowait(str("x: "+str(event.Position[0])+"    "+"y: "+str(event.Position[1])+"    "+"t: "+str(Tt)+"\n"))
            CLICKS.append(temp_l)
        return True
```

The problem is I can't stop the process with a function (behind a button):

```
win32api.PostThreadMessage(clickThreadId, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
```

So everything is working fine, but when I call root.destroy() I'm left with two background processes and my cursor freezes for about 5 seconds.
Does anyone know a way to handle this?

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to post `WM_QUIT` yourself, and there's no `PostThreadQuitMessage()`. Try sending the other process's main window a `WM_CLOSE` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`PostThreadMessage` isn't the right way to send a `WM_QUIT`. Raymond Chen has [more on that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453). The takeaway is that the `PostQuitMessage` can bypass filtering on the thread's message queue (among other things). Looking at the win32api python library, it does have the [`PostQuitMessage`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__PostQuitMessage_meth.html) function that you need to do that particular call, but that's not really a solution to the problem.

You'd actually need to be running a message loop on the individual threads, so they can see when the `WM_QUIT` comes in and deal with it appropriately. If you're not pumping messages on a thread, then you'll never get the quit message which leaves you with the zombie threads.

The solution is to mark your worker threads as [daemon threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) if they can be abruptly terminated, or to use something like an [Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event) to signal the threads that it's time to quit if they need to clean up after themselves.